# prestashop 1.7.8 give wrong number of Db::getInstance()->Affected_Rows()

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

presta 1.6 working well, but same php code in presta 1.7 give number afected > 0 when is = 0, i tested in Mysql and result is affected = 0

one of lots SQL which i use in one .php, only this and one other have this problem affected > 0 when is = 0

```
<?php
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
//products without imgs
$sql9="
UPDATE `"._DB_PREFIX_."product_shop` ps 
SET ps.`dm_google_active` = '0' 
WHERE ps.id_product IN (         
SELECT * FROM (Select DISTINCT(ps.id_product) 
from `"._DB_PREFIX_."product_shop` ps
LEFT JOIN `"._DB_PREFIX_."image_shop` pi 
ON pi.id_product=ps.id_product
WHERE pi.id_product IS NULL) AS wihoutImg
)";
    
if (!Db::getInstance()->execute($sql9)) {
    die('error! removing products without imgs from XML google');
} else {
     echo "Cron [removing products without imgs from XML google] done. <br> -> Rows Afected: ".Db::getInstance()->Affected_Rows()."</br>";
 }
```

give
`Cron [removing products without imgs from XML google] done. -> Rows Affected: 94`

presta 1.6 working well but same php code in presta 1.7 give number affected > 0 when is = 0, i tested in Mysql and result is affected = 0

this not help me

```
Db::getInstance()->disconnect();
Db::getInstance()->connect();
```

i try
`print_r($db)`
it give some like this

```
DbPDO Object ( [link:protected] => PDO Object ( ) [result:protected] => PDOStatement Object ( 
[queryString] => UPDATE `ps17_product_shop` ps SET ps.`dm_google_active` = '0' WHERE ps.id_product IN ( SELECT * FROM (Select DISTINCT(ps.id_product) from `ps17_product_shop` ps LEFT JOIN `ps17_image_shop` pi ON pi.id_product=ps.id_product WHERE pi.id_product IS NULL) AS wihoutImg ) ) 
[server:protected] => *** 
[user:protected] => *** 
[password:protected] => *** 
[database:protected] => *** 
[is_cache_enabled:protected] => 
[last_query:protected] => SELECT domain, domain_ssl FROM ps17_shop_url WHERE main = 1 AND id_shop = 1 LIMIT 1 
[last_query_hash:protected] => [last_cached:protected] => )
```

i commented some values by ***

Comment: Perhaps you should taise this as a potential bug with prestashop support.

Comment: I was wrong in interpreting my code, the code and Presta functions work fine. I apologize for the confusion. I'm not sure why the result was different in Presta 1.6, but I don't care because I don't use it anymore.

Comment: I think you should delete this question in this case